# Cognito: User Login to Authenticate DynamoDB: Error: Missing credentials in config:

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I'm getting the below error when I try to use Cognito to log into an authenticated user. I'm trying to access DynamoDB.

> Error: Missing credentials in config
>
> "NotAuthorizedException: Missing credentials in config

```
  AWS.config.update({region:'us-west-2'}); 
  if (cognitoUser != null) { cognitoUser.getSession(function(err, result) { 
    if (result) {

       console.log('You are now logged in.');
       AWS.config.credentials = new   AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
               IdentityPoolId: config.IdentityPoolId,
               Logins: {
                   "cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-2_XXXXXXX": result.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
               }
           });
       }
   });
  }



      var  dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB(AWS.config.credentials)            


       dynamoDB.listTables(function(err, data) {
           if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
           else console.log(data.TableNames);
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to call dynamo inside the `cognitoUser.getSession(...)`